# How to get mapbox style openmap with API key?

Tags: r, mapbox, openstreetmap

I'm trying to make a map in R using `OpenStreetMap` library.

I had no problem using types such as `osm`, `stamen-toner`, `stamen-terrain` and `stamen-watercolor`, for instance:

```
map <- openproj(openmap(c(63.47,10.32),c(63.37,10.54),type='osm'),proj=CRS('+init=epsg:32632'))
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(map)
```

works just fine:

[image: map]

I'll add the points over that layer. However, my client wants a [`map-box`](https://i1.wp.com/blog.fellstat.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Rplot001.png) type, but when I run

```
map <- openproj(openmap(c(63.47,10.32),c(63.37,10.54),type='mapbox'),proj=CRS('+init=epsg:32632'))
```

I get the following error:

```
failed loading 12/2165/1106 Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/examples.map-zr0njcqy/12/2165/1106.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoidGhlZmVsbCIsImEiOiJjaXN1anNwODEwMWlrMnRvZHBhamRrZjlqIn0.Gf8qLSpZ6yo5yfQhEutFfQ
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.cens.spatial.RTileController.getTileValues(RTileController.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Error in osmtile(x%%nX, y, zoom, type) : 
  could not obtain tile: 2165 1106 12
```

I know I need an API key. I've created one at [MapBox site](https://www.mapbox.com/). But now, how do I get a map of `map-box` type? The examples given are like

```
apiKey <- paste0('?access_token=','{my key}')
baseUrl <- 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}'
map <- openproj(openmap(c(63.47,10.32),c(63.37,10.54),type=paste0(baseUrl,apiKey)),proj=CRS('+init=epsg:32632'))
```

I tried replacing `satellite-streets-v9` with `mapbox` or simply deleting this directory, but it doesn't work. I don't know how to add my API key to the original command `openmap(c(63.47,10.32),c(63.37,10.54),type='mapbox')`. I couldn't find anything useful on mapbox's website, either.

Comment: does your map have to be static, or is an [interactive one acceptable](https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/articles/mapdeck.html) ?

Comment: @SymbolixAU All I need is to produce a single PNG file, with a few layers above the original map. If an interactive map can yield such a result, then it's fine to me.

Comment: Maybe you can use `mapdeck` and add [layers as you wish](https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/articles/layers.html), then save a screenshot?

Comment: @SymbolixAU Well, it may work. But I'm sure there must be a way to do it as intended. After all, `mapbox` is the name of the site!! And a screenshot? I need an image bigger then my own screen.

Comment: When I run the first code snippet above I get `Error in CRS("+init=epsg:32632") : could not find function "CRS"`. (Removing the `CRS` call results in a distorted map, whereas the graphic in your question has the "proper" aspect ratio, which is what I want.) Do you know why this error occurs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SlowLearner Sorry, the `CRS` function is from the `rgdal` library. You'll have to run `library(rgdal)` first, and probably `install.packages('rgdal',depend=T)` before.

Comment: I will do that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enter [Mapbox Studio](https://studio.mapbox.com), create a default style (similar to the `mapbox` style I desired), to see on the "Layer overview" window that their default theme is called "Mapbox Streets v8". From there, I guessed that I should use

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v8/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}
```

as my `baseUrl`. And it worked!